# Check if a command returns nothing in Makefile

Tags: c, linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

For a C library, I need to check whether the current compiler is for x86_64 due to memory issues. The command I found that exactly meets my requirement:

```
CXXARCH:=$(${CXX} -dumpmachine | grep -i 'x86_64')
```

where `${CXX}` is either `gcc` or `clang`. For an `x86_64` machine, this will return a non-empty string. For a 32-bit machine, say Raspberry Pi, this will be empty.

how can I distinguish between the two cases?

I did this:

```
ifneq (${CXXARCH},)
MAGICVAR:=-DMY_DEFINE
endif
```

With an `$(info)` print, I ensured that in a Raspberry Pi, this condition is not being fulfilled, which it should, because the command `clang-6.0 -dumpmachine` returns: `armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`. So why is this condition not being executed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not Makefile but shell syntax! See `$(shell )`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Apologies, I'm not that familiar with plain makefile nuances because I deal normally with cmake. This syntax works for other things in the make file I'm working with (which I didn't create myself).

Comment: It very probably is in the *executed part*. In any case, this will *always* result in an empty string being assigned to CXXARCH.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Actually adding `shell` before that `${CXX}` doesn't make it work.

Comment: of course it doesn't. See my answer

Comment: *"The command I found that exactly meets my requirement..."* - That does not work with Oracle's SunCC or IBM's XL C/C++ (or several others). As far as I know it only works for GCC and ICC, but you should include `CXXFLAGS` in case `-m32` or `-m64` is present. Clang will provide incorrect results when cross-compiling. Clang will show the host's arch, and not the target's arch.

Comment: *"I'm not that familiar with plain makefile nuances..."* - Here's a [GNU makefile](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile) that is doing the sort of thing you are working on.

Comment: @jww I use mxe for cross compiling and `./i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -dumpmachine` returns `i686-w64-mingw32.static`, which differs from `g++ -dumpmachine` that returns `x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax

```
$(${CXX} -dumpmachine | grep -i 'x86_64')
```

is *shell* syntax. It doesn't do what you want in a `Makefile`. To expand the CXX variable in *Makefile*, the preferred syntax is to use `$(CXX)` (while `${CXX}` works too, but **`$CXX` does not**). To capture the shell output you need to use `$(shell command)`. Thus

```
CXXARCH:=$(shell $(CXX) -dumpmachine | grep -i 'x86_64')
ifneq ($(CXXARCH),)
MAGICVAR:=-DMY_DEFINE
endif
```

---

Notice that the compiler target has *nothing to do* with "memory issues" in a *resulting program*. You can use `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` to compile 32-bit programs (-m32) and get the "same memory issues" that you'd have with a 32-bit compiler.

---

Finally make sure that you've not confused `ifneq` and `ifeq`.

```
ifneq ($(CXXARCH),)
```

means "if `$(CXXARCH)` does *not* expand to an empty string, then..."

Comment: I checked many times that I used your exact syntax, but the if condition is not being entered at all (ensured this is the case by adding an `$(info)` call there. Is there something else that can be done to check this? (btw, about the memory thing, I need to know whether the addressable memory is 32-bit or 64-bit; this seems the only clean way I found).

Comment: That's the thing that I commented in the last para. If `-m32` is in args then the addressable memory is 32-bit. `-dumpmachine` will give `x86_64-linux-gnu`.

you can `$(info $(CXXARCH))` and `$(info $(MAGICVAR))` (or `warning` to make it more visible). Works for *me*.

Comment: Actually, `clang-6.0 -m32 -dumpmachine` returns `i386-pc-linux-gnu` on an x86 machine.

Comment: doesn't do for gcc. And you don't provide those flags in the CXX command anyway. But, perhaps you've confused `ifeq` and `ifneq`

Comment: Some time in the future we'll be moving to cmake... then we'll be using `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`. Anyway, can you please help as to why the if condition is not being entered?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I've edited the answer once more, this time a pure PEBKAC error.

Comment: The `make` command is required to recognize `${variable}` notation as equivalent to `$(variable)` — by POSIX and ever since `make` was first released. Many people use parentheses; I almost invariably use braces in my makefiles.  You might be referring to the `$(…)` notation for shell command substitution, which would probably need to be written `$$(…)` to be handled properly.

Comment: GNU make functions are a whole separate bag’o’worms.  It’s likely good advice. I still work without the GNU functions.

Comment: You should use `grep -i -c 'x86_64'`, and then compare against `0`. Something like `ifneq ($(CXXARCH),0)`. Also you will misdetect 64-bit on a couple of platforms that use other strings, like `amd64` or `i86` in the case of Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a POSIX system, pipe the results through `wc -l`:

```
CXXARCH:=$(shell $(CXX) -dumpmachine | grep -i 'x86_64' | wc -l)
```

If the result is zero, there were zero lines with `x86_64` in it.  That's easier to handle in a makefile than a string value.

(including fixes to get shell syntax)

Comment: the `wc -l` is not really needed there, now you've made it more complicated ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The numeric value is easier to handle in a makefile.  ;-)

Comment: Than ifeq against an empty string? :D doubtful